# Camera calibration: is this radial distortion? How do I undistort it?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

[image]

This picture is taken directly from the wide-angle video camera under test, and the intention is to undistort the picture by camera calibration. However, as far as I know, current techniques are based on the assumption that the distortion is radial (tangential distortion is negligible), and then model the radial distortion with a high-order polynomial. Radial distortion is **uniform in each radial direction**, so the picture should look like this:

[image]

Clearly the distortion we have here isn't uniform in each radial direction. Does the current techniques still apply? What is a good way to correct this kind of distortion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an aspect ratio problem as well.  Most likely, the aspect ratio is a separate problem from the radial distortion and can be corrected independently.

The aspect ratio is likely a consequence of the sensor in your camera.  It may be possible to remove by changing the software configuration of the camera, or it may inherent in the shape of the pixels on the actual sensor.  In any case, you should be able to correct it by scaling the image appropriately in one direction.

The radial distortion is a consequence of the lens system; you can correct it by modeling the distortion.  Different wide-angle lenses may have different kinds of radial behavior at the periphery, so it may be best modeled either as a straight-up polynomial, or as a polynomial combined with a tangent, or as some other correction on a polynomial.

Additional fit parameters, such as an offset for the center of radial distortion, may also be appropriate.

Comment: So the first step would be to scale the image so that the distortion is actually radial and then carry out the calibration, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's the appropriate order.  Although, determining the scale of the distortion is also a calibration thing -- unless your camera manual tells you the exact scale of the distortion, or you guess at an exact ratio...